# Converting PDFDocument to NSString

Tags: macos, cocoa, pdf, aes, nsurlsession

I'm trying to upload a PDF to my server by converting the PDFDocument, which I get from the `pdfView.document()` (I'm using Quartz), to a NSData Object and then to a NSString. Later on I want to encrypt the String via AES.
I also want to display the uploaded String as a PDF (from NSString to NSData)

I tried this but when I'm calling `let stringFromData: NSString = NSString(data: pdf, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)` the debugger says:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Can somebody help me?

Or should I upload the entire PDF to a directory on my server? If yes, could somebody explain how and how can I guarantee safety for the PDF (for example how can I decrypt the file on the server)?

Thank you in advance,

Tom

Comment: As you have discovered, you cannot convert a PDF to a string. You can treat it as a blob (NSData), and if you want to encrypt that, you have to use an encryption method that works on blobs (binary data). That being said, PDFs can be encrypted when they are created, in which case you do not need to add an extra layer of encryption.

Comment: Thank you very much! I hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

The PDFDocument object has a property `string`, which represents the entire text of the document.

[Here's Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartz/pdfdocument/1436036-string)